# By what mechanism does Generic interact with Aeson's ToJSON class?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Looking at part of the `servant` [example](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html), I see:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Main where

import Prelude ()
import Prelude.Compat

import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.String.Conversions
import Data.Time.Calendar
import GHC.Generics
import Lucid
import Network.HTTP.Media ((//), (/:))
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Servant
import System.Directory
import Text.Blaze
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8
import qualified Data.Aeson.Parser
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html

type UserAPI1 = "users" :> Get '[JSON] [User]

data User = User
  { name :: String
  , age :: Int
  , email :: String
  , registration_date :: Day
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON User
```

When I removed the `deriving` of `Generic`, I got the following error:

```
• No instance for (Generic User)
    arising from a use of ‘aeson-1.1.2.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON’
```

So, it appears that the `Generic` typeclass instance for `User` enables `instance ToJSON User` to, I'm assuming, create a JSON `Encoder` for `User`.

What's the machinery of `instance ToJSON User`, i.e. type signature, if that's the right word?

I'm trying to look at its type from the `stack ghci`, i.e. REPL, but failing:

```
λ: >:t instance
<interactive>:1:1: error: parse error on input ‘instance’
λ: >:i instance
<interactive>:1:1: error: parse error on input ‘instance’
```

Comment: `instance ToJSON User` is just a regular class instance. You're probably used to seeing `instance ToJSON User where { ... }`. When there is nothing in the body of the instance, you can omit the `where` (In fact, if you enable `DeriveAnyClass`, you can even just put `ToJSON` in the `deriving` clause of `User`). The reason `Generic` "enables" `ToJSON` is that `ToJSON` has a [default implementation that relies on `Generic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:toJSON).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at [the source](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.2/aeson-1.1.2.0/src/Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.html#ToJSON) for `ToJSON`:

```
class ToJSON a where
    -- | Convert a Haskell value to a JSON-friendly intermediate type.
    toJSON     :: a -> Value

    default toJSON :: (Generic a, GToJSON Zero (Rep a)) => a -> Value
    toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

The `ToJSON` class has a default `toJSON` implementation with additional type constraints (including `Generic`, as you've noticed). This requires the [`DefaultSignatures`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDefaultSignatures) extension; notice at the top of that module you can see

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
```

The other constraint, `GToJSON Zero (Rep a)`, imposes some further restrictions on the structure of `a`, and so not *every* type with a `Generic` instance will satisfy this signature.

Regarding your question about GHCi: `instance` is a Haskell keyword. Inspecting `toJSON` may be what you want instead. This will show you the same information we saw in the source:

```
λ> :i toJSON
class ToJSON a where
  toJSON :: a -> Value
  default toJSON :: (GHC.Generics.Generic a,
                     GToJSON Zero (GHC.Generics.Rep a)) =>
                    a -> Value
  ...
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.1.2.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON’
```